# Recycler View Repeats

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat app using Kotlin and firebase and running the below functions to generate the ChatList on the frontend. It runs fine on load. But the second a user sends a message, it loops the output the same no of times as items already in the mUsers arraylist? Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

[Output of below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z0pF.png)

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false)

    recycler_view_msgList = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_msglist)
    recycler_view_msgList.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recycler_view_msgList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    usersMsgList = ArrayList()

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ChatList").child(firebaseUser!!.uid).orderByChild(
        "chattimeStmp"
    )
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            (usersMsgList as ArrayList).clear()
            for (dataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                val messageList = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageList::class.java)
                (usersMsgList as ArrayList).add(messageList!!)
            }
            (usersMsgList as ArrayList<MessageList>).reverse()
            retrieveMessageList()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })

    updateToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token)
    return view
}

private fun retrieveMessageList() {
    mUsers = ArrayList()
    (mUsers as ArrayList).clear()
    val arraysize = usersMsgList!!.size
    val i = 0
    for (eachMessageList in usersMsgList!!) {
        if (eachMessageList.getId() != null) {
            val receiverId = eachMessageList.getId()
            if (receiverId != null) {
                val ref =
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(receiverId)
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        for (dataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                            val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                            if (user != null) {
                                (mUsers as ArrayList).add(user)
                            }
                        }
                        userMsgAdapter = UserMsgAdapter(context!!, mUsers as ArrayList<Users>,true)
                        userMsgAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        recycler_view_msgList.adapter = userMsgAdapter
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    }
                }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you're retrieving the messages multiple times. In fact, your code can be a lot simpler:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false)

    recycler_view_msgList = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_msglist)
    recycler_view_msgList.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recycler_view_msgList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    usersMsgList = ArrayList()
    userMsgAdapter = UserMsgAdapter(context!!, mUsers as ArrayList<Users>,true)
    recycler_view_msgList.adapter = userMsgAdapter

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ChatList").child(firebaseUser!!.uid).orderByChild(
        "chattimeStmp"
    )
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            (usersMsgList as ArrayList).clear()
            for (dataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                val messageList = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageList::class.java)
                (usersMsgList as ArrayList).add(messageList!!)
            }
            (usersMsgList as ArrayList<MessageList>).reverse()
            userMsgAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            throw error.toException() // never ignore errors
        }
    })

    updateToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token)
    return view
}
```

With the code above you can remove `retrieveMessageList` completely, from what I can see. You simply create an adapter and register a listener for the messages once in `onCreateView` and then tell the adapter when the data has been modified.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for looking at this, I am using retrieveMessageList to get details about each user present in the userMsgList. If I do not run retrieveMessageList, mUsers is empty and ChatList would be blank...

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that. But the view is showing a list of messages right? Either way: you should craete the adapter in `onCreateView` as I've done here, and on on `onDataChange` as that gets called repeatedly. You should usually only need a single adapter instance for the entire lifetime of the view,.

Comment: ah, yes the view is confusing, had to mask sorry, its a chat list, I have two adapters running - One to get the list of chats a user is having and two to get the User Objects to populate the ChatList view on the front end. The issue i believe is because I am trying to loop through the query by querying for the specific user rather than loading the whole Users node and then populating mUsers, is my approach wrong? - the outside loop is on the userMsgList object array...

Comment: In general, this is an antipattern: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(receiverId)`. When storing user profiles, it is recommend to use their UID as the key. With that, the above code becomes: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(receiverId)` and you don't need the loop in `onDataChange` anymore (since you're reading one specific node already).

Comment: antipattern - oh ok, will move away from this approach then, will take it step by step, thanks Frank, cheers